# How to update OpenVPN Server on Windows?

Tags: windows, vpn, installation, openvpn, updates

I have OpenVPN 2.6.6 installed on Windows 10, configured to run as a server.

For security reasons, i like to keep all components of my server up to date, and when i noticed that OpenVPN 2.6.7 had been released ([See Here](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/)), i realised i don't actually know how to update OpenVPN...

Do i:

A) Run the MSI installer for 2.6.7, and install 'on top' of the current installation, and hope the installer automatically overwrites the appropriate binaries etc.

B) Uninstall 2.6.6, and then run the 2.6.7 MSI installer. (How will my config files, residing in subdirectories of `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN`, be affected?)

C) Something else

Sorry for the idiotic question, have looked for some OpenVPN docs regarding the matter, have not yet found any...

Comment: You'd do A - the only customized portion of OpenVPN are the files in the config folder and where the certs and keys are. General FYI, it's generally not recommended to run a VPN server in this way since the server's keys are directly accessible from a user account, unless customized ACLs have been configured to only allow the server access to the keys. It's why it's recommended to either do so on a router, within a router OS, or from within a locked down VM whose only purpose is to run the OpenVPN server. Windows simply doesn't provide enough security to guarantee a MITM attack never occurs

Comment: Right, thanks, i will try A. Regarding your FYI, i thought i was increasing security (Not to mention functionality!) by running my VPN server on my server machine rather than my router, as i can use a proper PKI rather than user/pass auth, have more control over open ports, clients, etc. Theoretically, if somebody has access to my servers complete file system, i already have a problem, right? (The Windows machine is my home server, not a general purpose machine...)